# pip list returns -bash: pip: command not found

Tags: python, pip

I am checking the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) and there are basically two ways to install `pip`.

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade

Looking in links: /var/folders/d0/gnksqzwn2fn46fjgrkp6045c0000gn/T/tmpe2ll6upv
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (58.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

All the packages are in `/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages` directory including `pip`.

However, when I run `pip list` from `base` environment, I get:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

I am getting `module not found` error when running my application.

My application was running fine until I tried to upgrade a python package. What did I mess up? What do I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `python -m pip list` instead of `python pip list`

Comment: I get `/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed`

Comment: I guess you have multiple versions of Python installed. Could you try python3.9 -m pip list ?

Comment: same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that pip might not be installed or it could be the version of the pip might not be compatible with the current version.

pip used for python2, use pip3 for python3 and upgrade your pip and retry once.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: `python -m pip3 install --upgrade pip3
/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python: No module named pip3`

Comment: Can you try un-installing the pip and install